# Add ordinal suffix if a record already exists in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mariadb, sequelize.js

Right now when file already exist I added prefix which is a timestamp to the filename to make it unique.

But I wanted to implement an ordinal suffix. so If I add a file with a filename for example helloworld and the file exist so the new filename would be now helloworld-1st and then if I add again it would be helloworld-2nd and so son and so forth. Anyone has an idea how to implement this ? the query below is already working for checking records. Thank you.

For example there is an existine file in the databse with filename hello .

If I add a filename with hello , the new filename now would be hello-1st.
And then I add file with filename hello again  so the new filename now is hello-2nd , if I add hello again , the new filenmae now would be hello-3rd so on and so forth.

#code to check if file already exists

```
 const file = await context.service.Model.findOne({
    where: { humanId: record.id, filename: data.filename },
    paranoid: false,
  });

if (file) {
    const prefix = Date.now().toString();
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    const fileParts = data.filename.split('.');
    filename = `${fileParts[0]}-${prefix}.${fileParts[1]}`;
  }
```

#Ordinal suffix function

```
function ordinal_suffix_of(i) {
    var j = i % 10,
        k = i % 100;
    if (j == 1 && k != 11) {
        return i + "st";
    }
    if (j == 2 && k != 12) {
        return i + "nd";
    }
    if (j == 3 && k != 13) {
        return i + "rd";
    }
    return i + "th";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```js
const data = [{
  "filename": "path.ext"
}, {
  "filename": "path.ext-1st"
}, {
  "filename": "path.ext-2nd"
}]

const ordinal_suffix_of = i => { var j = i % 10, k = i % 100; if (j == 1 && k != 11) { return i + "st"; } if (j == 2 && k != 12) { return i + "nd"; } if (j == 3 && k != 13) { return i + "rd"; } return i + "th";};

const incFile = filename => {
  const fileParts = filename.split('.');
  const [suffix,ord] = fileParts[1].split("-");
  let num = ord ? parseInt(ord) : 0;
  fileParts[1] = suffix + "-" + ordinal_suffix_of(++num);
  return `${fileParts[0]}.${fileParts[1]}`
};

const newFiles = data.map(({filename}) => incFile(filename))
console.log(newFiles);
```

Comment: should be path-1st.ext

Comment: also it should base the ordinal to the record in the database , for example what If I add the same filename 3 times or multiple times?

Comment: See update. Changes .ext to .ext-1st, changes ext-1st to ext-2nd and so on